# I have a web service that is misbehaving in Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

First off, I have about 10 web services configured in application insights for each of our environments (dev/test/stage/prod). 9 of them are operating as expected. However, one of them is displaying very odd behavior. They are all configured the exact same way. One of them is misbehaving.

What it is doing:

- **No** exceptions are getting logged. We see them in our Serilog database logging, but they are not showing up in Application Insights.
- Telemetry events are getting duplicated. For EVERY telemetry event, there is an exact duplicate registered.

I have scanned the web, and have not run across anything as of yet that addressed the issue. Can someone please help?

More information:

- App service:

  - .Net 7
- Visual Studio:

  - Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 Version 17.7.4
- Packages:

  - Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore - 2.21.0
  - Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector - 2.21.0

Here is the code in startup:

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>((module, o) => module.EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation = true); //
var telemetryClientConfig = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
telemetryClientConfig.ConnectionString = Configuration["ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"];
var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(telemetryClientConfig);
_ = services.AddSingleton(telemetryClient);
```

Other than that, we have the connection string in the appsettings.json. Like I said we have 9 other web apps, all with the same code / config / packages. This is the only web site misbehaving.

Comment: Could you please share the configuration and code of your WebApp.

Comment: Will be very interested to learn what the issue was (so, copilot could help with such cases in the future :))! If you can open a support ticket - this is the best way to get support directly from a team who owns this area. I also recommend to file it as GitHub issue.

Comment: @Harshitha added the code. The config is super simple and is just the connection string.

Comment: @SpaceGhost440 - Is the configuration and code is same in all the apps ?

Comment: @Harshitha Yes, it is.

Comment: @SpaceGhost440 - Can you please share the code repro of the app which is not working ?

Comment: @Harshitha Its the same as what I posted.